Entity Framework reference to an unique key as foreign key
I have a data model that has BOTH a primary key and a unique key.
When I am at the referencing class and try to use a foreign key annotation, I can't explicitly specify that I want to reference the unique key.
[ForeignKey("StatusRef")]

I ended up getting error like this:

System.InvalidOperationException : The relationship from 'SummarizedPart.LocationNavigation' to 'Location.Parts' with foreign key properties {'LocationRef' : string} cannot target the primary key {'LId' : Guid} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of foreign key properties with compatible types for this relationship.

Question: how do I reference an unique key?

Could you please provide both entities and their configuration?

In general you can configure this by using the following code:
modelBuilder.Entity<Blog>().HasMany(e => e.Posts).WithOne(e => e.Blog).HasPrincipalKey(e => e.AlternateId);
But in your case there seems to be a type mismatch also.

@decius...the primary key is a GUID; the unique key is a string...because EF doesn't know how to map to the unique key, thus the type mismatch.
